# Reduce time complexity in formatting loop

Tags: javascript, time-complexity

I am writing a component in Vue that lets us take an array of objects for a table and apply HTML formatting to the data, but the way I have it written currently is an O(n^2) complexity, and I am not sure how to make it any faster.

example `row` data:

```json
[
    {
        "product": "Socks",
        "price": 39,
        "sales": 20,
        "inventory": 68
    },
    {
        "product": "Shoes",
        "price": 23,
        "sales": 99,
        "inventory": 79
    },
    {
        "product": "Pants",
        "price": 45,
        "sales": 46,
        "inventory": 58
    }
]
```

example formatter array:

```js
[
    {
        data: 'product',
        format: (data) => {
            return '<em>' + data + '</em>';
        }
    },
    {
        data: 'price',
        format: (data) => {
            return '$' + data + '.00';
        }
    },
    {
        data: 'sales',
        format: (data) => {
            return '<span class="text-success">' + data + '</span>';
        }
    },
    {
        data: 'inventory',
        format: (data) => {
            return '<span class="text-primary">' + data + '</span>';
        }
    },
];
```

And here is the code that takes the formatter and applies it to the data:

```js
for (let row of rows) {
    let renderedRow = {};
    for (let key in row) {
        let format = render.find(renderObject => renderObject.data === key);
        renderedRow[key] = format.format(row[key]);
    }
    renderedRows.push(renderedRow);
}
this.rows = renderedRows;
```

The loop iterates over the `rows` and then iterates over the object in the `row`. Inside the object's loop, it finds the formatter (`renderObject`) with the matching key where `data === key`, and then uses the `renderObject`'s `format` function to apply the formatting and push the data to a new array.

Because the formatting needs to be applied to the data in every row, I tried to just access it using the `key`, but since each key is inside an object inside an array I couldn't figure out how to access that.

Comment: This is not O(n^2). You are iterating only once over each cell

Comment: I thought it was O(n^2) because I'm looping over the rows and then looping over the "columns" in the rows?

Comment: Ahh, I see. So then that's correct, it's not necessarily O(n^2) unless the number of columns = rows, which is possible with this component, just not necessarily this example.

Comment: I understand why this can be confusing. But just because you have two loops doesn't make it O(n^2) think of it like a 1 dimensional array versus a two dimensional array. The two arrays can contain the exact same set of data just broken ininto rows and columns. Does that change the order of magnitude to iterate over all of the elements? No, it doesn't. You are still only going over your entire data set only *once*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple thing you could do is take the `find` call and change it to a look-up table computed before the nested loop starts:

```
const formatters = Object.fromEntries(render.map(({ data, format }) => [data, format]));

for (let row of rows) {
    let renderedRow = {};
    for (let key in row) {
        let format = formatters[key];
        renderedRow[key] = format.format(row[key]);
    }
    renderedRows.push(renderedRow);
}

this.rows = renderedRows;
```

Comment: This is great! it worked and is noticeably faster on larger tables being formatted. Thank you!